# Android Studio rendering issues because of missing class

Tags: android, rendering

```
http://i.gyazo.com/f8e34c7f62ba659a1d9cb7c6a82103f9.png

Rendering Problem
    The following classes could not be found: 
    - adroid.support.v8.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout
```

I launched Android Studio and create a new project using API 15 and a blank activity, and this instantly turns up. I can load the app fine on my phone but I just don't understand the issue.

http://i.gyazo.com/56c140be1acb170b2c1812b40e842592.png

There is a copy of my build path, I'm not sure if that is helpful.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem but it didnt seem to affect my project i would just keep building and try changing your api to 21